# Solving $\frac{x}{2x + 1} + \frac{1}{ x-1} < 0$.

Tags: inequality

Solving $\frac{x}{2x + 1} + \frac{1}{ x-1} < 0$. after unifying the denominator I got $\frac{x^2 + x + 1}{2x^2 - x -1} < 0 $, then what shall I do?

Thanks!!

Comment: Set both the numerator equal to zero and the denominator equal to zero. This is where the expression will (possibly) change signs. Then you plot some points in between and around the critical points (where the expression $= 0$) to determine the sign of the expression in that interval.

Comment: Clearly the numerator is $>0$ for real $x$  So we need the denominator $<0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\frac{x^2+x+1}{(2x+1)(x-1)} < 0$, but $x^2+x+1 > 0$ for all $x$. Then it becomes $(2x+1)(x-1) < 0$ or $-\frac{1}{2} < x < 1$.

Comment: what if I did not see that the numerator is always > 0, how can I solve it by perfect squaring, I need a general method please.